# AWS Certificate manager configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, aws-acm

I have requested SSL cert from my CA after CSR submission. So i have 4 certs given by the CA. Normally i pasted following in order for my nginx ssl (ON PREM servers) .
But how can import those in ACM.
i have following

1. Private key
2. primary certificate
3. intermediate certificate
4. the root certificate.
   I normally append all those to generate the key for nginx.
   But which part should be added to each section of the ACM.

I'm guessing following in ACM.

Certificate body - this should include all 4 certs (append one after other)
cert primary key - its 1
Certificate chain - optional  - what should i include here ? or can i just ignore this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACM asks for 3 values:

**Certificate Body:** This is your primary certificate

**Private Key:** This is your private key. You should **NEVER** combine the private key with the values from your other files. This should always be separate.

**Certificate Chain (optional):** In your case this would be the root certificate and the intermediate certificate(s) concatenated together.